# navigation to the webpage was canceled webbrowser control c#

Tags: c#

i started a create a simple web browser...
when i code it web page is not loading...

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        webBrowser1.Navigate("textBox1.Text");
    }
}
}
```

This is the error when i go to a web page.

[image]

Comment: Why are you 'double-quoting' the `textBox1.Text` statement?

Comment: thanks. you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you used the `""` literals, you told the `Compiler` to treat what is between these `""` as a literal string and not a valid `C#` expression. So the expression will not be evaluated. And your `WebBrowser` control will receive this literal string `"textBox1.Text"` exactly as it is. And not the `Text` property of `textBox1` Control. By removing these `""` literals:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
```

Your `WebBrowser` control will receive the value of `Text` property of the `textBox1` control.

Answer (score 1):

use `webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);` instead